# Get-ChildItem in powershell 5.0 and 5.1

Tags: powershell

Does anybody knows why `ls -LiteralPath c:\data -Recurse -Include *.txt` command  works differently on powershell 5.1 and 5.0?

I have a folder with files:

- data

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file1.txtfoo

And if we run command listed above on machine with Powershell 5.0 then it will give you first two files as a result. But if you run the same command on machine with Powershell 5.1 then it will give you all three files.

Why it's happening?

UPD:
If we change `-Include` to filter then it works fine on both machines.
The same if we replace `-LiteralPath` with simple path string: `ls c:\data -Recurse -Include *.txt` then it will also work fine on both machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This appears to be a bug with `5.1` that was resolved in `6.1.0-preview.2`.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6865)

Comment: Please don't post [link only answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). It is in danger of being deleted by review queue users.